# transfer checked values of datagridview from one form to another form datagridview

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 forms and one datagridview in each form which are databound. In the first form (form1) I have a checkbox column and I want to transfer the checked rows to the second form (form2), but I don't want to transfer all the columns from the first datagridview. I am working with datasets. Can somebody help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This Code

```
In this code 
1. FORM1 GridView Select the Row 
2. Checked In Checked Box 
3. Click button 
4. Show Gridview In Form2
```

My Model Class

```
public class Student
{
    public int studentId { get; set; }
    public String StudnetName { get; set; }

}
```

My Form1 Code

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<Student> Students = new List<Student>();
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Student Stu = new Student();

            Stu.studentId = 1;
            Stu.StudnetName = "Kasun";
            Students.Add(Stu);

            Student Stu1 = new Student();

            Stu1.studentId = 2;
            Stu1.StudnetName = "Kasunjith";
            Students.Add(Stu1);

            Student Stu2 = new Student();

            Stu2.studentId = 3;
            Stu2.StudnetName = "dsdsdsd";
            Students.Add(Stu2);


            dataGridView1.DataSource = Students;

        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {




        }

        private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {



        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
            {
                int RowIndexCheck = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

                String id = dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndexCheck].Cells["studentId"].Value.ToString();
                String Name = dataGridView1.Rows[RowIndexCheck].Cells["StudnetName"].Value.ToString();

                Student studentsobj = new Student();
                studentsobj.studentId = Convert.ToInt32(id);
                studentsobj.StudnetName = Name;
                Form1 form1 = new Form1();

                Form2 form2 = new Form2(studentsobj);
                form1.Hide();
                form2.Show();

            }

        }
    }
```

Form1 UI 
[image]

My Form2 Class

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        List<Student> Studentslist = new List<Student>();
        public Form2(Student Stu)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Studentslist.Add(Stu);
        }






        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dataGridView1.DataSource = Studentslist;
        }
    }
```

Form2 UI

[image]

Comment: this think that you create works fine, but i have checkboxcolumn in the datagridview which is an unabound column. how to solve that.In addition i want to pass more than one values.

Comment: I will try to answer.